# django filter gte and lte on one property of one model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a `User` model with `age` property

my models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

i need to output all users `between age 25 and 35`

i can only make query which won't exclude others users

```
first_query = User.objects.filter(age__gte=25)
second_query = User.objects.filter(age__lte=35)
```

can i output users `between age 25 and 35 and exclude others`, in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
User.objects.filter(age__gte=25, age__lte=35)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#lte

Comment: Or, to make the point that filters stack (as do all other things which return querysets): `User.objects.filter(age__gte=25).filter( age__lte=35)`

Comment: @nigel222 Or can also be `User.objects.filter(Q(age__gte=25) & Q(age__lte=35))`